Cannot send message to SQS from AWS Lambda function
I have a Lambda function that has some data and must send it to a SQS queue. But it seems like the send is not working. There is no error and it seems to gracefully continue execution without any message being sent. Here is my Lambda code:
  //JavaScript

  import { SendMessageCommand, SQSClient } from "@aws-sdk/client-sqs";
  
  const message = {
    label: "test",
  };

  const client = new SQSClient({});
  const SQS_QUEUE_URL = "https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/...";

  const send = async (message, sqsQueueUrl = SQS_QUEUE_URL) => {
    const command = new SendMessageCommand({
      QueueUrl: sqsQueueUrl,
      DelaySeconds: 5,
      MessageAttributes: {
        Label: {
          DataType: "String",
          StringValue: message.label,
        },
      },
      MessageBody:
        "Sent test data to SQS queue",
    });
    const response = await client.send(command);
    return response;
  };
  
  const doSend = async(message, SQS_QUEUE_URL) => {
    const response = await send(message, SQS_QUEUE_URL);
    response.then(function() {
      console.log("Message has been sent to SQS Q1");
    }).catch(function() {
      console.log("Something went wrong");
    });
  };
  doSend(message, SQS_QUEUE_URL);

Viewing the logs on CloudWatch, I can see the "Test" message being printed, but not the response. I have other things after the send(...), all that code works, it's just the send(...) that isn't doing anything. My runtime is Node.js 20.x.
I have already attached a policy to provide full SQS access for my Lambda function. I also included the region when initializing the client, didn't seem to make a difference.

client.send returns a promise, so if you'll need to handle the promise appropriately

What is the correct syntax here to handle the promise? This is what I tried:
const response = await client.send(command).then(function(message) console.log(message); }).catch(function(error) {console.log(error); }) return response;};
My queue is not receiving messages still.

Is your SQS Queue Access Policy allowing the lambda function to send messages to the queue? Just to make sure since you should recieve an exception if there is not such configuration

Yes, I have given SQSFullAccess for my lambda function. I'm not even getting an exception

Your send method is returning a promise so you have to wait for the response(await send(message, SQS_QUEUE_URL)) in order to fulfill the request made by the SQS client(client.send), otherwise the lambda instance will finish before. I don't know how you are setting up the lambda handler but I'll give you an example of how you should restructure the code.
import { SendMessageCommand, SQSClient } from "@aws-sdk/client-sqs";

const message = {
  label: "test",
};

const client = new SQSClient({});
const SQS_QUEUE_URL = "https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/...";

const send = async (message, sqsQueueUrl = SQS_QUEUE_URL) => {
  const command = new SendMessageCommand({
    QueueUrl: sqsQueueUrl,
    DelaySeconds: 5,
    MessageAttributes: {
      Label: {
        DataType: "String",
        StringValue: message.label,
      },
    },
    MessageBody:
      "Sent test data to SQS queue",
  });
  console.log("Test");
  const response = await client.send(command);
  console.log(response);
  return response;
};

export const handler = async (event) => {
  // Your code here

  await send(message, SQS_QUEUE_URL);

  // Your code here
};


I made the change and handled the promise, but nothing is still printed to the console in my doSend(). No messages are shown in the SQS queue either. Post was updated with the new code.

I tested the same code and it worked for me, maybe is something with your lambda, can you try creating a new lambda function with nodejs 20? Also can you share the response you are getting?

Also I saw you edited your post, the response variable in the doSend method is not a Promise so then isn't gonna work, you should use console.log(response) directly. I don't see an entry point in your lambda function, in the code I shared the entry point is the handler async function, you should put the doSend call inside the lambda handler. If you try creating a new lambda and test it with my code it will work.

I see. I had dedicated a different function that I called from my handler to take care of some data processing that I didn't want to do in my handler. I made those changes and now I do get an error which is a good sign, I'm getting: __type: com.amazon.coral.service#SerializationException "message": "Start of structure or map found where not expected.", at await client.send(command);. My data doesn't seem to be malformed, I suspect it's how the command is structured? My queue is the standard queue, not FIFO

Make sure you are sending a string in the MessageBody as well in the MessageAttributes.Label.StringValue. The command object structure is ok. You can read about the SendMessageCommand structure here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/client/sqs/command/SendMessageCommand/

Great, it worked! Apparently, they weren't strings beforehand (I had assumed). Thanks for the help.

Could you please try to catch any errors and let us know what the error message is? If no error occurs, the MessageID should be printed
const doSend = async (message, sqsQueueUrl) => {
  try {
    const response = await send(message, sqsQueueUrl);  
    console.log("Message has been sent to SQS Q1:", response.MessageId);   
  } catch (error) {   
    console.error("Something went wrong:", error);
  }
};


There is no error, but there is also nothing being printed according to CloudWatch
